# EXC_BAD_ACCESS glGetShaderInfoLog - How to proceed?

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I'm using Marmalade C++ and Open GL ES 2.0.  Several tutorials I am working through and I keep getting the same error:

EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the call to glGetShaderInfo()

Here's my code.  How do I proceed in a situation like this?

```
static int eglInit()
{
    if (!IwGLInit() )
    {
        s3eDebugErrorShow(S3E_MESSAGE_CONTINUE, "eglInit failed");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

const char* vShaderStr =
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = vPosition;\n"
    "};\n";

const char* fShaderStr =
    "precision mediump float;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

GLuint LoadShader(GLenum type, const char *shaderSrc)
{
    GLuint shader;
    GLint compiled;

    // Create the shader object
    shader = glCreateShader(type);

    if (shader == 0)
        return 0;

    // Load the shader source
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderSrc, NULL);

    // Compile the shader
    glCompileShader(shader);

    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);

    if (!compiled)
    {
        GLint infoLen = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
        if (infoLen > 1)
        {
            char* infoLog = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * infoLen);

            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
            printf("Error compiling shader:\n%s\n", infoLog);

            free(infoLog);
        }

        glDeleteShader(shader);
        return 0;
    }

    return shader;
}

int main()
{
    if (eglInit())
        return 1;
    printf("Screen BPP: %d\n", s3eSurfaceGetInt(S3E_SURFACE_PIXEL_TYPE) & S3E_SURFACE_PIXEL_SIZE_MASK);
    printf("\n");
    printf( "Vendor     : %s\n", (char*)glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
    printf( "Renderer   : %s\n", (char*)glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    printf( "Version    : %s\n", (char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    printf( "Extensions : %s\n", (char*)glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS));
    printf("\n");

    GLuint vertexShader;
    vertexShader = LoadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vShaderStr);

    bool quit = false;
    int numFrames = 0;
    while (!quit) {
        s3eKeyboardUpdate();
        s3eDeviceYield(0);
        if (s3eDeviceCheckQuitRequest())
            quit = 1;
        if (s3eKeyboardGetState(s3eKeyEsc) & S3E_KEY_STATE_PRESSED)
            quit = 1;
        numFrames++;
    }
    //Shutdown GL system
    IwGLTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
```

you are passing a `NULL` as a third parameter, which should accept a `GLsizei*` instead. This parameter (the third) [is populated](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml) with the real length of the info log and should therefore be a valid pointer.

To solve the issue you can just do:

```
GLsizei info_length = 0;
glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLen, &info_length, infoLog);
```

Comment: @icktoofay, No. The returned value for `infoLen` is: "the number of characters in the information log for shader including the null termination character" ([reference](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderiv.xml)).

Comment: Awesome, this works.  Thanks.  I wonder why all these books and tutorials I am reading supply a NULL for that value.  I checked the documentation and as you say NULL doesn't make sense to put in there.

Comment: @SeanBollin: Because it is not required, a compliant OpenGL / ES implementation is supposed to ignore it if you pass `NULL`. Apparently yours is non-compliant :-\ Also, you really should be using `infoLen - 1` for the length of the shader. What you got when you called `glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);` was the length of the string (including the NULL terminator). You only allocated enough storage for `infoLen - 1` characters because you need an extra byte for the NULL terminator.